# Quick question about the definition of a random variable in a baseball pitches example

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, definition, negative-binomial

[image: Screenshot from my textbook]

I'm just wondering, in the last sentence of the third paragraph, why can X not be larger than 6? Is that because the number of innings is 9? I'm really confused, I thought X goes from 3,4,5,6,...to infinity?

Comment: Full count is three and two. If you don't swing you can't get a foul ball so you either strike out or walk on the sixth pitch.

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm still confused, but thank you for your answer. I was wondering if you can you still strike out for X=7? For example, if one hit/hit/hit/hit/strike/strike/strike for a total of 7 pitches, they can still strike out this way -- am I interpreting the concept of striking out correctly? I'm also not sure what you mean by full count.

Comment: They don't swing.  After 6 pitches, there are two **mutually exclusive** possibilities: 4 balls, or 3 strikes.  One of those two possibilities must occur, since if there were only 3 balls and two strikes, only 5 pitches are thrown.  Once either event occurs (4 balls or 3 strikes) the at-bat is over, and either the batter walked or struck out.  Note that the walk or strike out might not require 6 pitches.  However, the walk or strike out can **not** require **more** than 6 pitches.

Answer (score 1):

Each pitch results in either a ball or a strike. If you get to three strikes you are out. If you get to four balls then you walk. If you have thrown five pitches and have neither struck out nor walked then you must have three balls and two strikes. On the next pitch you either get a ball in which case you have four balls and you walk or you get a strike in which case you have three strikes and you are out.

The batter is either out or has walked by the sixth pitch.